# Some features in QGIS layer will export to DXF but others (in same layer ) will be missing

Tags: qgis, layers, features, dxf

Everything I've ever exported to dxf (Project-> Export...) has worked or if not it has been somehow explicable and fixable.

I don't understand why, if I have nine features on a layer, all identical in symbology and labeling but with unique fid's and coordinates, only six will export.

Has anyone experienced this before?

I'm using QGIS 3.20.3

I have opened the dxf in several ways which confirm that three of the nine features just aren't there.

Comment: Test data would be useful. Or do you mean that it happens with any data if you just have exactly nine features on the layer?

Comment: Not exactly.  I only happened to notice it it with this one layer that happens to have nine features.  It was consistently exporting only six of the the nine (always the same six). I just created a new layer with the same points and that layer will only export seven of the nine.  So that's even more mystifying.  I've exported several layers (with many more features in them) from this project so I'll need to confirm that it hasn't happened with the others.

Comment: Can you convert all features into shapefile or GeoPackage? What if you convert this shapefile/GeoPackage into DXF with ogr2ogr without using QGIS?

Comment: Update: I created a scratch layer, defined the same nine points and exported that.  It exported correctly.  Then I saved that layer to a gpkg and reinserted it into the project.  That new layer will only export the same six features and not all nine.

Comment: I converted that single layer into its own gpkg and then converted that to a dxf with ogr2ogr, as you suggested.  All nine features do show up, albeit at the wrong scale.  
But it does retain all nine.
However, if I then add that gpkg to the same project and use the project export functionality of QGIS it will only export the same six points.  
I may downgrade to 3.16 to see if there is any difference.

Comment: It appears that checking "Export features intersecting the current map extent" exports all of the features.  But this doesn't make sense to me because A) I've exported several layers with points well outside of the current map extent without issue and B) the points that were consistently missing were well inside of the map and layer's extents. This seems like odd behavior.

Comment: There must be something special in your case. The "Export features intersecting the current map extent" should export the whole layer or subset of the layer depending on how much data fits on the map. Perhaps coordinate systems play some role, for example if some of the features are outside the valid area of the crs.